# Reducing tuple values with reduceByKey in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, mapreduce

I'm starting to work with the MapReduce paradigm with Pyspark, I'm stuck with a problem and I don't know if it a programming error or that I shouldn't do it this way.

I have data from which I am extracting the following information with `map` for each line:
`(id, (date, length, counter))`, I did it this way to extract all the info I need from the raw data file and filtering the noisy lines so I don't have to use the raw data file again. Btw: Counter is originally 1, and it is intended for addition in future `reduceByKey`.

Now the data looks like this:

`data = [('45', ('28/5/2010', 0.63, 1)), ('43', ('21/2/2012', 2.166, 1)), ('9', ('12/1/2009', 2.33, 1))]`

First, I am trying to count the number of key-value pairs, so it is a simple `reduceByKey` adding the counters, I tried to do it this way: `data.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a[2] + b[2])` which provides the following error `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

If `a` and `b` are supposed to get the value of the pair, the element `2` is supposed to have the counter of it, I cannot get my head around it. Is it better to map several times the raw data file extracting every-time a different needed value? Should I map this `data` variable extracting `(key, value)` pairs each time with the value needed from the tuple? Is it just that I'm making a programming error?

Any guidance is welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue. 
When reducing for example `(id, (x, x, 1)), (id, (y, y, 1)), (id, (z, z, 1))`, in the first reduce you would obtain `(id, 2), (id, (z, z, 1))` so when trying to reducing again, the number `2` in the first element is non subscriptable, I must keep the data structure during the process.